# Is my step by step derivation of quadratic cost function's (Neural Networks) partial derivative with respect to some weights matrix correct?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, derivative

I am trying to revise the details of a Multi-layer Perceptron with a set of weight matrices $\mathcal W$ and a set of bias vectors $\mathbf b$. Here is the quadratic cost function I am using,

$$C(\mathcal W, \mathbf b) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x(y-a^L)^2$$

I understand that in order to run (Stocastic) Gradient Descent we need the gradient of the cost function $\nabla C(\mathcal W, \mathbf b),$

$$\nabla C(\mathcal W, \mathbf b) = \Bigg[\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^2}, \frac{\partial C}{\partial b^2}, ... , \frac{\partial C}{\partial w^L}, \frac{\partial C}{\partial b^L}\Bigg]$$

Here is my question, for some layer $l$, is my derivation of $\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^l}$ correct (I am nervous about a negative sign)?

\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial C}{\partial w^l}
  & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \Bigg( \frac{\partial (y-a^l)^2}{\partial (y-a^l)} \frac{\partial (y-a^l)}{\partial w^l} \Bigg)
  && \frac{\partial f(g(x))}{\partial (x)} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \\ 
  & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \Bigg( \frac{\partial (y-a^l)^2}{\partial (y-a^l)} \Big(\frac{\partial (y)}{\partial w^l} - \frac{\partial (a^l)}{\partial w^l} \Big)\Bigg)
  && \frac{\partial (f \pm g)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial (f)}{\partial x} \pm \frac{\partial (g)}{\partial x} \\
  & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \Bigg( \frac{\partial (y-a^l)^2}{\partial (y-a^l)} \Big(0 - \frac{\partial (a^l)}{\partial w^l} \Big)\Bigg)
  && \frac{\partial (y)}{\partial w^l} = 0 \\
  & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \Bigg( \frac{\partial (y-a^l)^2}{\partial (y-a^l)} \Big(- \frac{\partial (a^l)}{\partial w^l} \Big)\Bigg) \\
  & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \Bigg( - \frac{\partial (y-a^l)^2}{\partial (y-a^l)} \frac{\partial (a^l)}{\partial w^l} \Bigg)
  && \text{Brought the } (-) \text{ up front} \\
  & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \Bigg( -\frac{\partial (y-a^l)^2}{\partial (y-a^l)} \Big(\frac{\partial (\sigma(z^l))}{\partial z^l} \frac{\partial z^l}{\partial w^l} \Big)\Bigg)
  && \text{Chain Rule} \\
  & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \Bigg( -\frac{\partial (y-a^l)^2}{\partial (y-a^l)} \frac{\partial (\sigma(z^l))}{\partial z^l} \frac{\partial z^l}{\partial w^l} \Bigg)
\end{align*}

Evaluating differentials,

\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial (y-a^l)^2}{\partial (y-a^l)}
  & = 2(y-a^l) \\
  \frac{\partial (\sigma(z^l))}{\partial z^l}
  & = \sigma'(z^l)
  && \sigma'(x) = \sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x)) \\
  \frac{\partial z^l}{\partial w^l}
  & = \frac{\partial (w^l a^{l-1} + b^l)}{\partial w^l} = a^{l-1}
\end{align*}

Therefore,
$$
  \frac{\partial C}{\partial w^l} =
  \frac{1}{n} \sum_x \Bigg( -\frac{\partial (y-a^l)^2}{\partial (y-a^l)} \frac{\partial (\sigma(z^l))}{\partial z^l} \frac{\partial z^l}{\partial w^l} \Bigg)
  = \frac{1}{n} \sum_x (-2(y-a^l)\sigma'(z^l)a^{l-1})
$$

I accumulate a negative sign in front which makes me nervous because I did not see it at other places (though I do understand the choice of a half in front of the quadratic cost function but I chose not to add it).

I did also find places which had a negative sign upfront like me: [here](https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/) and [here](https://medium.com/swlh/backpropagation-step-by-step-13f2b6c0b414).

So, is my derivation of $\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^l}$ correct?

Comment: Can you link to a source that shows how to get a derivative of an equation with a summation sign?

Comment: It is not any different than normal polynomial derivatives. e.g., let $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{2} x^i = x^2 + x^1 + x^0 = x^2 + x + 1$. In this case, $\frac{df}{dx} = 2x + 1$.

Comment: You maybe interested in [Neural Networks: The Backward Pass](https://tashfeen.org/net/two.html).

Comment: So I basically have to write out the summation as the "long-form" equation?

Comment: I am not sure about all things that can be written as a summation but for polynomials you don't have to write out the long form, you just have to *imagine* it. Though, you can write it out if it helps you in certain cases but it may not be always feasible. Consider: $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{2^{100}} x^i$. Here we know that $\frac{df}{dx} = \sum_{i=1}^{2^{100}} ix^{i-1} = \left(\sum_{i=2}^{2^{100}} ix^{i-1} \right) + 1$.

Comment: Please take what I say as advice from another student. I am by no means a derivatives expert. You might consider https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I will answer my own question since I feel more confident after doing some more research.

> Is my step by step derivation of quadratic cost function's (Neural Networks) partial derivative with respect to some weights matrix correct?

Yes, It is. Though, the notation maybe sloppy.

> I accumulate a negative sign in front which makes me nervous because I did not see it at other places

Sometimes, other derivations online distribute the negative sign and rewrite the final result in such a way that does not start with a negative sign at front. I missed the distribution and that made me feel nervous about me having a negative sign at front.

---

Finally, [Neural Networks: The Backward Pass](https://tashfeen.org/net/two.html) has the same derivation with a little less sloppy notation.